# try to get matplotlib legend items in reversed position

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I am trying to reverse items which appear in matplotlib legend i.e. I'd like to have the label of a point in the first position and the "mark-symbol" of a point in the second position of the legend. So just reverse situation to that shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried moving the text and the line properties of the legend? Something like

```
leg = legend()
txt = legend.get_texts()[0]
txt.set_x(-20)
line = leg.get_lines()[0]
line.set_xdata( line.get_xdata() + 20)
```

For multiple legends, and more generally, this becomes

```
LINEOFFSET=20
TEXTOFFSET=-20

leg = legend()
for txt in legend.get_texts():
    txt.set_x(TEXTOFFSET)
for line in leg.get_lines():
    line.set_xdata( line.get_xdata() + LINEOFFSET)
```

Adjust `LINEOFFSET` and `TEXTOFFSET` until you get the desired result.